# Custom compass on android google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, compass

I would like to add a custom compass to the map or replace the current icon and items. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map does not give this functionality that easily replace compass with your custom image.

But one way is **disable default compass via setCompassEnabled and draw your own. Use sensors to make it point in the right direction.**

you can use following example to point right direction. see below link.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/08/simple-compass-sensormanager-and.html